# How to limit Google Cloud Platform "BigQuery Metadata Viewer" permission?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I have 10 tables under my dataset. I need to create "BigQuery Metadata Viewer" permission but would like to neglect 2 tables under my dataset. So that BigQuery Metadata Viewer policy only will be able to access 8 tables.

I see that there is "condition" tab but could not figure out how to apply such a condition here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM condition is a nice way to solve that issue, but it's not available for [BigQuery resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resources).

The solution here is to have 2 datasets

- One with the 8 tables and the permission to view the metadata
- one with the 2 other tables without the permission to view the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GRANT` statement using the role [bigquery.metadataViewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#:%7E:text=BigQuery%20Metadata%20Viewer) or [dataviewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#:%7E:text=BigQuery%20Data%20Viewer).You can set this role to table level, the user will have permission to a specific table, and won’t see listed tables. In this case, you need to know the name tables.

Take a look to this example:

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer`
ON TABLE `my_dataset._my_table`
TO "user:user@domain.com"
```

Additionally, you can  set this role at dataset level, this will [grant access](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-control-language#grant_statement) to read and list all the tables from the dataset.

Here’s an example:

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer`
ON schema `project_name.dataset_name`
TO "user:mail@mail.com"
```

Comment: What if I would like to create service account with this role to use in my application? Not to grant that privilage to any user.

Comment: @Enes You can use these queries for grant permission to service account and use with an API. Just need to write the service account instead the user account

Comment: @Enes Did you have time to test my answer?

Comment: Hello coulnt try to solution, due to covid dieasese, I will try and comment soon. Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried this, even tought query succeded service account is not updated unfortunately. Maybe bigquerymetdataViewer policy is not eligible for table bases.

Comment: I of course changed from TO "user:..."  to TO "serviceaccount:....."